# Jquery show/hide element based on mysql selection

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I wanted to show/hide element based on MySql Value

```
$(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', '#composeHeaderTable0', function(event) {
    if ($('#data_parent_type0').val() == 'Leads') {
    $("#email_template0 option[value='151ddf5a-3fe8-84bd-50db-533545893c67']").hide();
    $("#email_template0 option[value='15a6040b-bbad-1a89-d62b-537de2b73832']").show();
}
    if ($('#data_parent_type0').val() == 'Contacts') {
    $("#email_template0 option[value='1b560788-07b2-0798-6b09-5335520bd9df']").hide();
    $("#email_template0 option[value='f15bf4b4-d174-f0d6-6f09-537c8d3e9693']").show();

}
    return false;
});
```

Above script works, but I need to show hide based on Mysql call:
I have partial php corresponding file

```
<?php
    mysql_connect('mysql', 'admin', '123');
    mysql_select_db('mydb');
    $Leads0emailAddress0 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Leads0emailAddress0']);
    $result = mysql_query('select id from email_templates where description = 'Customers' and deleted = 0;');
...............
?>
```

Comment: in what you are going to show or use the sql return value??

Comment: `description = 'Customers'` should be `description = "Customers"` (with double quotes) since you are using the single quotes as surrounding quotes for query.

Answer (score 1):

Use a hidden form element, set its value to the result obtained from mysql. Assign a specific ID to that form element. From jQuery, refer that form element using the ID. That should do the trick.

Comment: Yes, I know.
I don't know how to get the MySQL output into the:
$("#email_template0 option[value='value from MySQL']").hide();

Comment: Try using  value='<?php echo $result ?>'

Answer (score 0):

Your mysql script has error

```
    $result = mysql_query('select id from email_templates where description = 'Customers' and deleted = 0;');
```

change it to

```
    $result = mysql_query(
              "SELECT id FROM 
                  email_templates 
                WHERE 
                  description = 'Customers' 
                AND deleted = 0"
             );
```

To list the result

```
$options = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       $options .= '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['id'].'</option>' . "\n";   
}

//display the options list in html where you want
<select id="email_template0">
   <?php echo $options; ?>
</select>
```

now from jQuery handle event on dropdown change

```
 $(function() {
 $("#email_template0").change(function() {
    alert( $('option:selected', this).val() );
    //do your hide and select here 
    });
 });
```

Comment: Great, thanx, that's the php part.
What would be the jquery for the same? Keeping in mind there are 2 queries for Contacts and Leads.

Comment: I'm still not able to get it.
This is the php
<?php
        $con = mysql_connect('mysql', 'admin', 'admin');
        mysql_select_db('suitecrm');
        $data_parent_type0 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['data_parent_type0']);
        $result = mysql_query('SELECT id FROM email_templates WHERE description = "'.$data_parent_type0.'" AND deleted = 0');
        $options = '';
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $options .= ''.$row['id'].'' . "\n";
        echo $options;
}
        mysql_close($con);
?>

Comment: And this is the jquery
$(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', '#composeHeaderTable0', function(event) {
$("#data_parent_type0").change(function() {
        var data_parent_type0 = $('#data_parent_type0').val();
        $.post("etplate_dbcall.php", { data_parent_type0: data_parent_type0},'html');
});
        $("#email_template0 option[value='$options']").show();
});

Comment: The PHP returns the correct 'id', but the jqyuery is not re-posting